# Prove that probability of choosing an isosceles traingle in Set of traingles is $0$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, euclidean-geometry, geometric-probability

> $S$ is set of triangles of unit area. All members of $S$ are uniformly distributed. Let $A$ be the event that a randomly chosen member of $S$ is an isosceles triangle. Prove that the probability of $A$ is zero.

Set up a probability model in which all members of $S$ are uniformly
distributed. The choice of the model is up to you. You could view
the members of S as members of $R^6$, or $R^3$ or $R^2$, depending on
how you choose to describe a triangle. You could even choose a
representation in some other set,

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Do you mean that $S$ is **a** set of triangles of unit area, or **the** set of **all** triangles of unit area?

Comment: S is a set of all traingles of unit area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say we have a triangle with sides $a,b$ and angle $x$ between them. Then, since the area is $1$ we have $$a\cdot b\cdot \sin x =2\implies \sin x ={2\over ab}$$

So all we have to chose is $a$ and $b$.
Since $0<\sin x\leq 1$ and $a,b>0$ we have $$ b\geq {2\over a}$$

So the sample space is $$\Omega = \{(a,b);\; b\geq {2\over a},\;a>0\}$$

and we are interested in event $$\color{\red}{A =\{(a,b);\; b=a,\;a\geq \sqrt{2}\}}$$

[image]

Comment: which angle is x exactly? angle between sides a and b?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: how does it even prove that event E has probability 0?

Comment: if x is the angle between a and b, you assumed sinx = 1 which means for x = pi/2. This logic only applies to right angled triangle then.

Comment: Probably with some limit. Instead of all $\Omega$ you take a part of it and a part of halfline, say $x,y\leq n$ and then take a limit of a sequence which is always 0?

Comment: Where is $\sin x =1$?

Comment: Sorry i didn't see >= sign. But still your method is not correct.

Comment: Why?...................

Comment: @joriki Is this OK?